# Old header saved on HTTP Header Manager being used instead of updated one

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

I have saved the HTTP Header Manager information for an endpoint as below:
[image]

However, when i execute this test plan i see in the test results tree view, many of the hits fail. I figure from the response headers i see there that it is using the header value i had put in earlier.

[image]

Why are these history values being used? How do i get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check the request start time, it might be the case you're looking at "old" results and you need to scroll down to see "new" results. Alternatively you can invoke `Clear all` menu entry which will remove all the previous results, logs, etc.

   [image]
2. Running tests in GUI mode should only be used for development and debugging, for your 100 threads you should switch to [command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
3. Also when you're done with designing your test consider removing all the listeners as [they don't add any value and just consume valuable resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing). More information: [Reducing resource requirements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. I had already tried the "Clear All" option, and it does clear older run results. But when i re-run the test plan again i see multiple outputs (like i posted in the image) using older header values and the last run is a success using the latest header info i set. I was saving the header using "import fro curl". Need to search a bit on that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a Header Manager for the specific http request (HTTP Sampler). You need to override the values in the individual HTTP Sampler's Header Manager. JMeter follows hierarchy where you can override values at node level.

Comment: Thanks. I am using a header Manager for the specific http request.

Comment: which header value you expect to change? and, what scripting/configuration have you done so that new values are sent?